# Feed Dialog - "An error occurred. Please try again later"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code to post into users wall.I took this code from developer.facebook. But getting error like "An error occurred. Please try again later" while opening the dialog.

```
FB.ui(
  {
method: 'feed',
name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
caption: 'Reference Documentation',
description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications"
 },
   function(response) {
if (response && response.post_id) {
  alert('Post was published.');
} else {
  alert('Post was not published.');
}
 }
 );
```

Please share ideas to fix this

Comment: Were you in any way able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10):

In my case i just set my application at the facebook developer site to be **public**

[image: set the app public]

Comment: Thank you! It turns out, that as an app creator, I'm an admin, and admin can always use FB.ui (in my case: 'send') without problems. Lesson learned today: always test your as an unprivileged user before deploying to production :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on the description: line. this code:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applic\
ations'
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    }
 );
```

Works on fbrell.com for me.

Answer (score -1):

eosgood is right, you have a type-o in your code.  However, for others, this might help...

I had the same problem.  Things to try:

- Move the FB.ui javascript to the very end of the page, so it's the last script executed.
- Doublecheck to make sure you have `<div id="fb-root"></div>` immediately after the opening body tag.