# Why is getSessionFromRedirect() return a NULL?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code which redirects the user to log into facebook and tries to retrieve the session but the session is NULL:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('Foo', 'Bar');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('Baz');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();  

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log In</a>';  

$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();  

// This displays [NULL] always
echo '[' . gettype($session) . ']';

?>
```

I don't understand why the $session is always NULL. Please help.

Answer (score 23):

> It happens because of the getLoginUrl() function,
>
> because when we mentioned same page as FB redirect page, it call `getLoginUrl()` function again and again.. which change `$this->state` variable value
>
> and then `isValidRedirect()` and  `getSessionFromRedirect()` always return null

Here is solution to use same page as FB redirection page:

Don't call `getLoginUrl()` when facebook redirect you to same page, just add the proper session check to check valid facebook session (Please refer following code example)

```
session_start();
require("facebook/autoload.php");


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appid84', '0secret0a626c6');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://tmd.local/fblogin.php');

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  // var_dump($session);
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
}
if ($session) {
  var_dump($session);
}
else
{
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
  header("location:".$loginUrl);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: In simple words, Don't call the $helper->getLoginUrl() before $helper->getSessionFromRedirect() if you are using same page for login and redirect_uri

Comment: @Faraz you got the correct point, I already showed that using code snippet but now more clarification I have added the more info and updated the ans.

Answer (score 8):

You should be calling getSessionFromRedirect only on the page Facebook redirects the user to after login.  Then store that session somewhere, like $_SESSION, and re-use it elsewhere.

The issue is, when you generate the login url again, it changes the 'state' variable used to protect against CSRF.

Comment: But this is what I do. It just happens that the page is the same.

Comment: The issue is, when you generate the login url, it changes the 'state' variable used to protect against CSRF.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work, I'm going to post an answer with code snippets.

Comment: @SBel please check my ans. if you still want to implement same page for FB redirection

Comment: It's not awesome to post your own answer when this is the one that answered things for you.

Comment: @fosco i agree.. but i am just helping some who want to implement logic with single page.. i didn't see the anybody posted answer in that way.. which help readers quickly.. so i posted..

Comment: Store what in SESSION and how?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so the goal was to get a `FacebookSession`. There needs to be 2 pages: 1 for displaying the Log In link and the other to accept the instance of `FacebookSession`. In page1.php put:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('foo', 'bar');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('page2.php');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log In</a>';

?>
```

In page2.php put:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('foo', 'bar');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('page2.php');

// Now you have the session
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
?>
```

Thanks Fosco for your help.

Comment: Hi, I have same problem with you, but I use your code, I still get a null from getSessionFromRedirect. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the session loading, login redirect and API call all from the single page if required. [This tutorial shows you how it can be done](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem doing all of the above, and I fixed it by

> Changing the App Setting. Facebook Developers -> My App -> Settings -> Advanced -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs -> Add '/' at the end of the directory. If it's a file, then end the path at the directory that the file is in.

Answer (score 0):

Look at those two docs, those will help you resolving :)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi

Comment: When I was trying to get a session for a user I did read these pages (among other ones) but I still was not able to understand what to do. I find it difficult to start out with facebook's documentation and all the tutorial's online are for the previous PHP SDK version.

Comment: @SBel you can switch in the upper left of the doc site to v4 api docu ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php line 214!

change the $_GET['state'] with $_SESSION['state'] from this way:

```
  /**
   * Check if a redirect has a valid state.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  protected function isValidRedirect()
  {
    $savedState = $this->loadState();
    if (!$this->getCode() || !isset($_GET['state'])) {
      return false;
    }
    $givenState = $_GET['state'];
    $savedLen = mb_strlen($savedState);
    $givenLen = mb_strlen($givenState);
    if ($savedLen !== $givenLen) {
      return false;
    }
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $savedLen; $i++) {
      $result |= ord($savedState[$i]) ^ ord($givenState[$i]);
    }
    return $result === 0;
  }
```

to this:

```
 /**
   * Check if a redirect has a valid state.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  protected function isValidRedirect()
  {
    $savedState = $this->loadState();
    if (!$this->getCode() || !isset($_SESSION['state'])) {
      return false;
    }
    $givenState = $_SESSION['state'];
    $savedLen = mb_strlen($savedState);
    $givenLen = mb_strlen($givenState);
    if ($savedLen !== $givenLen) {
      return false;
    }
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $savedLen; $i++) {
      $result |= ord($savedState[$i]) ^ ord($givenState[$i]);
    }
    return $result === 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

What made the real difference to me was the redirect Url address i was using.
Hours and hours because of a slash.

Explaining with examples:

(Wrong)

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.example.com');
```

(Right)

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.example.com/');
```

I've read a ton of tutorials and answers on Stackoverflow and this final slash was the real answer. I hope it helps someone

Comment: This doesn't change anything. I've been putting / at the end and still having the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to put your redirect URI on facebook valid oauth?
Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28100164/1193038)