# Using Facebook SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to use `Facebook SDK v4` to let users login to my website.  I am able to click the `Log in` button on my `index.php` page, get redirected to facebook to login, and then I am redirected back to the same `index.php` page.  Unfortunately, when I am redirected back to my `index.php`, it is supposed to display my name (doing this to test out that I am logged in).  However, it just shows a log-in button again, which means that the Facebook session is not really active.  Look at code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php

    session_start();

    /* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILEs*/
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
    require_once( 'src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

/* USE NAMESPACES */

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

/*PROCESS*/

    //1.Stat Session

    //2.Use app id,secret and redirect url
     $app_id = '';
     $app_secret = '';
     $redirect_url='';

     //3.Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
     FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
     $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
     $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();


?>


<html>

    <head>

        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5">

                    <h1>
                    <?php

                        if(isset($sess)){
                        //create request object,execute and capture response
                        $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me');
                        // from response get graph object
                        $response = $request->execute();
                        $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
                        // use graph object methods to get user details
                        $name= $graph->getName();
                        echo "hi $name";
                    }else{
                        //else echo login
                        echo '<a href='.$helper->getLoginUrl().'>Login with facebook</a>';
                    }

                    ?>

                    </h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">

                    <a class="start-button btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(); ?>">Login</a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Note that my app id, app secret, and redirect url are purposely omitted.

Comment: Do a : var_dump ($sess); after : $sess = $helper->getS... and try to login and see what contains this object after redirection

Comment: @ELOUFIRHatim It returns a null.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @ELOUFIRHatim I tried all the solutions on this page as well (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526621/why-is-getsessionfromredirect-return-a-null).  I even tried passing the session to a different page instead of the same page.  It still returns a null session. Very frustrating haha.

Comment: On your api settings on facebook developper try adding '/' to your url settings like mentionned here : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues/204

Comment: Did the solution by EL OUFIR Hatim solve the issue?