# Facebook feed dialog is showing "An error occurred. Please try later"

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

Please help. The facebook feed is showing the following error

[image]

Please help. What should i do.

I am using facebook Javascript SDK, and here is my code to make a facebook feed. when i run this function a new window appears with this error

```
function fb_share() {

  var name = $('input.name').val();
  var link = $('input.link').val();
  var caption = $('input.caption').val();


    FB.ui( {
        method: 'feed',
        name: name,
        link: link,
        caption: caption
    }, function( response ) {
        if ( response !== null && typeof response.post_id !== 'undefined' ) {
            console.log( response );
        }
    } );

}
```

Comment: Specify what you are trying to do and what you have done so far. It will be helpful if you post your code to find the issue.

Comment: See the code above @ShankarPrakashG

Comment: It's already solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231939/redirecting-to-authentication-dialog-an-error-occurred-please-try-again-late?rq=1. check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check your Face book APP ID and APP secret . Maybe you did change App domain ( Eg:www.testing.com ) and Contact Email and click Add Platform. In your face book app.

[image]